# Error:(56, 21) error: non-static method getId() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am writing this code and it shows the error non-static method `getID()` cannot be referenced from a static context.
The error is in switch `(View.getID())`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button greetbutton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    greetbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.greetbutton);
    greetbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    TextView textView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    EditText editFreindname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFriendname);

    String freindname    = editFreindname.getText().toString();

    switch (View.getId()) {

        case R.id.greetbutton:

            textView.setText(getString(R.string.greetstring) + freindname + "!");

            break;

        default:

            break;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace `View` with `v` in your switch statement.  `View` is the name of the class, `v` is the variable you are trying to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace View with v.

try this 
v.getId() instead of View.getId() :)

Answer (score 0):

`getId()` is not a static method. You need to call it on an instance of the `View` class.

For example, these 3 uses of `getId()` are valid (`EditText` extends `TextView`, which extends `View`):

```
editFreindname.getId()
freindname.getId()
v.getId()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method as if it's static, since you're calling it using the class name:

```
View.getId();
```

`getId()` is non-static method you cannot call from a `View`.

Try

```
switch (v.getId()) {
```

instead of

```
switch (View.getId()) {
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the method using the class name.
You should use v instead of View. i.e

```
  switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.greetbutton:
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.greetstring) + freindname + "!");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```